# Borel $\sigma$-field in k is same as product Borel $\sigma$-field using open balls

Tags: measure-theory

I am supposed to prove "The Borel $\sigma$-field $\mathcal{B}^k$ of $\mathbb{R}^k$ is the same as the product $\sigma$-field of k copies of $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}^1)$."

I have already done the problem by showing containment both ways. For $\mathcal{B}^k \supset \otimes_{i=1}^k \mathcal{B}^1_i$ I used sets of the type $\{A\subset \mathbb{R}; A \times \mathbb{R}\times...\times\mathbb{R}\in \mathcal{B}^2\}$ and $\mathcal{B}^k \subset\otimes_{i=1}^k \mathcal{B}^1_i$ is pretty straight forward. (I suppose I shouldn't give too many details because this seems like a popular homework question).

However, the hint in this book (Schervish) says, "Hint: First, show that every open ball in $\mathbb{R}^k$ is the union of countably many open rectangles. Then prove that the smallest $\sigma$-field containing open balls must be the same as the smallest $\sigma$-field containing open rectangles."

I would like to understand how to do the question using the hint. Thanks!

Comment: Showing that every open ball is a union of countably many rectangles is essentially the same as showing that $\mathcal B^k\subseteq \otimes_{i=1}^k\mathcal B^1_i$. So your argument is very similar to the hint.

Comment: I am sorry. I do not understand why showing that every open ball is a union of countably many rectangles implies that. Also, I believe that part is the easier to show as {closed rectangles}$\subset \{B_1\times B_2 \times ...\times B_k;B_1 \in \mathcal{B}, B_2 \in \mathcal{B}  ...B_k \in \mathcal{B}\}$ It was the other direction that seemed difficult.